# Bash Script Cron Job

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I have installed PCoIP  Teradici PCoIP Solutions for linux in Centos 6.4. I want to get macAdress of HostCard,
when i run `pcoip_agent -info` it gives correct output using command line. I want make this cron job, for that purpose i write bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
hostcardMacAddress=$(pcoip_agent --info|grep  -F 'PCoIP Host card MAC:'|awk '{print $5}' > hostcardMacAddress.txt)
cat hostcardMacAddress.txt
```

after that i make this script a cron job but it gives empty macAddress.

Kindly help me. Thanks.

Comment: Is the `pcoip_agent` program in the standard search path? Cron jobs don't run your profile, so they won't find programs in unusual locations.

Comment: yes its is in /usr/bin/ folder where are executable scripts placed. i also tried using full path /user/bin/pcoip_agent -info but no output.

Comment: Try writing full paths of all binaries and files.

Comment: I have tried everything it works fine on command line,the problem occurred only when i run this script using cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Check the mail of the user that owns the `cron` job. There will be an error message indicating what the issue is.

Login as cron-job's user
enter `mail` and check for mail at the time the `cron` job was invoked.